# Error received when installing Grails birt-report plugin

Tags: java, grails, birt

I want to use BIRT Report on Grails, but when I install the birt-report plugin, it is not complete and returns an error. Can you help me with BIRT Reports and showing the BIRT Report Viewer on a GSP Page?

This error :

```
Installing BIRT v2.5.0 OSGI Platform libraries into C:/Users/Dev/.grails/1.3.4/projects/TestBirt/plugins/birt-report-1.0/lib ...
  [get] Getting: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
  [get] To: C:\Users\Dev\.grails\1.3.4\download\birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
  [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
  [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
  [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
  [get] Can't get http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip to C:\Users\Dev\.grails\1.3.4\download\birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
Error installing plugin: Can't get http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip to C:\Users\Dev\.grails\1.3.4\download\birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
  [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Dev\.grails\1.3.4\projects\TestBirt\plugins\birt-report-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug with the plugin and how it instructs Grails to get the appropriate package. I tried installing it as well and received the same error:

```
> grails install-plugin birt-report
...
Installing BIRT v2.5.0 OSGI Platform libraries into /root/.grails/1.2.3/projects/robapp/plugins/birt-report-1.0/lib ...
      [get] Getting: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
      [get] To: /root/.grails/1.2.3/download/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
      [get] Can't get http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip to /root/.grails/1.2.3/download/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
: Can't get http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip to /root/.grails/1.2.3/download/birt-runtime-2_5_0.zip
```

It appears that the package it's trying to access (R-R1-2_5_0-200906180630) isn't available [here](http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse/birt/downloads/drops/).

You can report a bug with the plugin [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel).

*Edit*:

Looks like you (or somebody) did report [a bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-2487), and it apparently has been fixed.